# JAXB - Initialize new objects when generating classes from XSD

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, jaxb

I'm working on a java project using Maven and Spring that uses JAXB to generate java classes from a complex XSD file. However if there are objects in the class I would like them be generated as new. I'm using Intellij to perform the generation.

For example if the resulting java class looks something like this (with all the auto generated comments removed so that you can read it easier)

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "car", namespace = "http://foo.bar.com/car/read", propOrder = {
    "driver",
    "licenseNumber"
})
public class Car {

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://foo.bar.com/car/read", required = true)
    protected Person driver;
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://foo.bar.com/car/read", required = true)
    protected String licenseNumber;

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(Person value) {
        this.driver = value;
    }

    public String getLicenseNumber() {
        return licenseNumber;
    }

    public void setLicenseNumber(String value) {
        this.setLicenseNumber = value;
    }
```

What I would like to do is initialize `driver` and `licenseNumber` as new objects instead of null. For example

```
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://foo.bar.com/car/read", required = true)
    protected Person driver = new Person();
    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://foo.bar.com/car/read", required = true)
    protected String licenseNumber = new String();
```

Is it possible to make JAXB generate the java classes this way? What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Not OOTB, but you can write a plugin to do this. Not sure why would you want it, though.